# magic matchsticks problem geeks for geeks interview question

Tags: java, arrays

I have given an interview in geeks for geeks where I was given a magic match sticks problem, I wasn't able to solve it in time. I solved it myself a day after, I wasn't able to find the solution as well on Stack Overflow, so here is the solution for you if you ever encounter that problem:

```
//magic match-stick problem
/*in this problem set we are given n number of match boxes, 
* you need to add matches in a match that is 
* the n number of matches in each box,
* but the catch is instead of adding the matches, 
* you need to subtract the matches pair that you will be inserting in place 
* of every new match stick until there is only last box left with final match stick score
* eg: 1st match box: 4match sticks: 1,2,3,4 match numbers
* 2nd time: 2 match sticks : (1-2), (3-4)=> 1, 1
* last time: (1-1) => 0
* 
* I know I cannot explain the problem correctly in English, but I will be able to explain it to you in hindi v well
* also if you can understand the code, you will understand the question
* this took me one day to solve, many minor mistakes I did
* this is a geeks for geeks interview question
* question name magical matchsticks*/

public class practice{
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int num;
        int count;
        int n = a.length;
        
        do
        {
    
            num=0;
            count=0;
            
            if(n==1)
            {
                System.out.println(a[0]+"last");
            }
            
            else if(n>1)
            {
                
                
                if(n%2==0)
                {
                    n=n/2;
                    
                    for(int i = 0; i<((n)) ; i++)
                    {
                        
                        a[i] = a[num]-a[num+1];
                        
                        if(a[i]<0)
                        {
                            a[i] = a[i]*(-1);
                            System.out.print(a[i]+" "+a[i + 1]);
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println(" a ");
                        
                        num = num + 2;
                        count++;
                        
                    }
                }
                else if(n%2==1)
               {
                    n = (n/2) +1;
                    for(int i = 0; i<(n); i++)
                   {    
                        a[i] = a[num]-a[num+1];
                        if(a[i]<0)
                        {
                            a[i] = a[i]*(-1);
                            System.out.print(a[i]+" "+a[i + 1]);
                        }
                        System.out.println("b ");
                        num = num + 2;
                        count++;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            System.out.println(n);
            for(int j = 0; j<a.length;j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(a[j]);
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
                
        }while(n>1); 
        
        
        for(int k = 0; k<a.length;k++) 
        {
            System.out.print(a[k]);
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        
        
    }
}
```

This problem will show you all the steps as the program goes on, you will need to make changes so it returns value from a separate class or function.

I'll be starting to provide solutions for competitive programming on this account.

Comment: Could you amend this question so that the question post is a question, and the answer is posted in the answer section? Thanks!

Comment: As interesting this is, this needs to be in Q&A format to be on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is solved with answer given above.

also answer is provided on my github page: **https://github.com/bruce-Wayn/java-qns/blob/6a9714225b4884aefbdad0441e721416c5843576/magic-match-sticks.java**